# Halachic dispute over 'Geshtuppte Ganz' (Goose Liver) - Stuffed-goose dish

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, chassidic-rebbe, poultry

I was reading the Artscroll biography of the [Tosher Rebbe](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/TOSHEH.html) and it writes on p.283 the following:

> He recalled how his grandfather the Saba Kadisha, had warned him against eating *geshtuppte ganz*, the stuffed-goose dish that was commonly eaten in Hungary. It was subject of fierce halachic dispute, and the Tosher Rebbe had held it forbidden.

The footnote there reads:

> This was questionable according to halacha because the food pipe might have developed a hole, as the geese were force-fed. While many Jews would eat this dish, there were several poskim who ruled it forbidden.

Building on the Rema as pointed out by @JoelK below, does anyone know of any sources / sheilos v'teshuvos that discuss this case further?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.33.9?lang=bi

Comment: Thanks @JoelK - I was aware of the halacha I just was interested in reading about this specific case

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by 'this specific case'?

Comment: This case of a stuffed goose dish and its specific discussion amongst the poskim....

Comment: That's what the Rema is discussing וכן נהגו להקל בעירנו באותן אווזות שמלעיטין לעשות מהן שומן

Comment: Yes - sorry I am not being clear. I realise this is the starting point I am looking for the sheilos u'teshuvos that develop the discussion.

Comment: Ah ok. Might be worthwhile following the links here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92527/force-feeding-of-geese/92576

Comment: relevant: http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=2706, https://www.jpost.com/judaism/you-can-now-eat-glatt-kosher-foie-gras-in-israel-635434, https://www.koshertoday.com/ou-ends-certification-of-foie-gras/

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/4694

Answer (score 1):

The [Seforim Blog](https://seforimblog.com/2018/10/foie-gras-fake-news-fictitious-rashi/) has an article discussing it.

Rabbi Dovid Cohen who is the
Administrative Rabbinic Coordinator of the CRC of Chicago has a shiur on this topic [here](https://www.crcweb.org/shiurim_dc/Meat/Meat%20and%20Poultry%2031%20(Specific%20Parts%20A)%20(Apr%209,%202021).mp3). (It's part of a longer series of shiurim [on kosher meat](https://www.crcweb.org/kashrus_shiurim.php#meat).)

Comment: Hi @Efraym - thanks for this. Could you perhaps provide a summary of what is said?